# What is the error getting in web scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am getting an error list index out of range in the last line . Also the containers variable is empty and it is giving out 0 when printed its length insted of 12. The containers variable should have contained all the details but it is not fetching anything.

```
  from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

  my_url='https://www.newegg.com/global/in-en/p/pl?d=graphics+card'
  uClient=uReq(my_url)  #opening the connecting,grabbing the page,this line downloads the web page

  page_html = uClient.read()   #this line dump every thing in the variable page_html
  uClient.close()         #close the connections.
  page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")           #html parsing
  #print(page_soup.h1)                       #this line print the header 

  #print(page_soup.p)

  containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": {"item-container"}})   #grabbing each product
  len(containers)
  containers[0]
```

Comment: This returns 36 containers for me so `containers[0]` is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `requests` like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
url = 'https://www.newegg.com/p/pl?d=graphics+card'
r = requests.get(url)
soup_page = soup(r.content,'html.parser') 
containers = soup_page.find_all('div',{'class':'item-container'})
print(len(containers))
```